# Cordova Build Hooks + Grunt

Tags: node.js, cordova, gruntjs

I am trying to link-up my cordova build with grunt, there are a tasks that we run when serving the project locally that I would like to reuse during our Cordova build.  For this I create a simple before_build hook and placed it in hooks/before_build.

My build hook looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var grunt = require('grunt');
grunt.tasks(['build']);
process.exit(0);
```

The initial part of the build works well, all of the files are copied as expected.  However, within my `build` task, I make several additional calls such as:

```
grunt.task.run('wiredep');
```

This, and all other similar calls, fail to execute without an error or warning.

**Why would I not be able to call additional grunt tasks?**

All of my tasks are defined in the Gruntfile using either `loadNpmTask` or `registerTask`, is this an incorrect configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Well... `grunt.task.run(...)` simply adds a task to Grunt's "queue" (of sorts), it does not immediately run that Grunt task. I think you may want to actually set your `build` task as the default in your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
```

Then just use a bash script (versus a Node shell script):

```
#!/bin/bash
grunt
```

Note that you will need to have the `grunt-cli` installed first:

```
~$ nmp install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: you were spot on, only I didn't even have to override the default task.  Also, careful with the `#!/bin/bash` that will only work on windows!

Answer (score 0):

I received some feedback on the Grunt issues board:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1265

Any time I need to call one of my Grunt tasks, I add a hook_task.sh file with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
grunt build
```

This **works on Windows/Linux/Mac** without any issues.

I would still like to know why the node approach was not working.  Part of me feels much more comfortable using that approach, but this is working well so no complaints.

(Note: My Gruntfile.js is in the root of my Cordova App)