# Down and dirty with Grunt configuration

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am new to GruntJs and I am trying to incorporate it within a Cordova application. It seems as though I am trying to use an advanced configuration of Grunt (calling Grunt from a separate node task) so I ended up checking out the source and there are some things I cannot figure out.

So having spent most of the day wrestling with Grunt configuration, here are my questions:

- **Where does the `Gruntfile.js` get loaded?  Is the process different if the `Gruntfile.js` is located in a parent directory?** (How/where is the task.init() called?)

As I said, I am trying to link up my Grunt tasks with my Cordova build.  Cordova allows this through several hooks, each will launch a separate node instance.

- **How do `grunt.task.run()` and `grunt.tasks()` differ when the both seemingly do the same thing?**
- **What is the difference between "running" grunt from the shell and "require" grunt from a node module?**

Any assistance in this matter would be appreciated.  For reference, the related Cordova question is here:
[Cordova Build Hooks + Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478566/cordova-build-hooks-grunt)